# culture in Media Manager distribution

Tags: 2013-sp1, media-manager

According to [official documentation,](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDLMediaManager213-v5?#addHistory=true&filename=GUID-4947787B-504A-4CCA-B236-6F1078636C02.xml&docid=GUID-E1FA024D-32C7-455F-80C4-61431F96F110&inner_id=&tid=&query=&scope=&resource=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-E1FA024D-32C7-455F-80C4-61431F96F110) I can query localized content from distribution by using `"culture"` property, for example:

```
https://<TenantName>.sdlmedia.com/distributions/?o=<GUID>&cultures=nl,en
```

But where can I set this `culture` property in Media Manager? I checked properties of programs, assets and distribution and cannot find it anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using culture limits what tracks are shown.

Tracks can be imported or created manually to include [languages](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDLMediaManager213-v5?#addHistory=true&filename=GUID-BAC9A68D-0354-4E7D-8BC4-4BA053BA90BF.xml&docid=GUID-BAC9A68D-0354-4E7D-8BC4-4BA053BA90BF&inner_id=&tid=&query=&scope=&resource=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-BAC9A68D-0354-4E7D-8BC4-4BA053BA90BF&url=/LiveContent/web/search.xql%3Fc%3Dt%26pub%3DSDLMediaManager213-v5%26lang%3Den-US%26action%3Dsearch%26query%3Dsubtitles&sid=lcSearch.runSearch1532588699924&currentQuery=subtitles&currentScope=) of which SDL Media Manager supports these [language & region codes](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDLMediaManager213-v5?#addHistory=true&filename=GUID-CE7F42C5-CC4B-4909-8F8E-4092E65F85DA.xml&docid=GUID-CE7F42C5-CC4B-4909-8F8E-4092E65F85DA&inner_id=&tid=&query=&scope=&resource=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-CE7F42C5-CC4B-4909-8F8E-4092E65F85DA&url=/LiveContent/web/search.xql%3Fc%3Dt%26pub%3DSDLMediaManager213-v5%26lang%3Den-US%26action%3Dsearch%26query%3Dculture&sid=lcSearch.runSearch1532588682563&currentQuery=culture&currentScope=).

Comment: Actually this is possible in media manager for videos only. Is there similar option for images? I want to pack 2 diff images in distribution, and then based on culture show one or another.

Comment: Tracks seem to be specific to videos - could you achieve what you want with labels? https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDLMediaManager213-v5?#addHistory=true&filename=GUID-4947787B-504A-4CCA-B236-6F1078636C02.xml&docid=GUID-A0B51A5C-7C79-43F3-A252-D9C974200F00&inner_id=&tid=&query=&scope=&resource=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-A0B51A5C-7C79-43F3-A252-D9C974200F00

Comment: yes, I figured they are for videos only. Now i am trying to set labels for client, and use them later in querying. Other option is to use keywords, but am not sure how to query by them.